# Can we restrict Syncing document libraries to specifc user/s only

Tags: document-library, onedrive-for-business, sync, onedrive

we have a modern communication site inside our sharepoint online. now on the document library i am enabling offline syncing:-

[image]

where currently all users who have access to the sites can sync the files and folders to their PCs (using OneDrive.exe or using OneDrive For Business). but can i restrict this?, and only allow certain user/s to be able to sync the document library files?

Comment: since they have permission to view on Document Library and you enabled Offline Client Availability, every user who has permission should be able to sync it. only thing you can customize and hide the Sync button using JS and css from document Library based on certain SP groups but its not good practice to do.

Comment: @vinitkumar so restricting syncing to specific users is not a supported operation??

Comment: No,it's not a supported operation as per i know. may be some MVP will have other thought.

Comment: @vinitkumar i also did not find any documentation mentioning this

Comment: @SharePoint TestDev : there is no such functionality available in sharepoint, whatever changes you are doing, its applicable for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, such option does not exist yet. The only option available is to prevent the role library to be synced which would affect all users who have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution will be to stop inheriting permission for that library and give contribute permission to users who should be able to sync the document libraries.

To stop inherit permission follow this [link](https://www.cloudfronts.com/restrict-download-and-print-option-for-sharepoint-online-document-library/)

Comment: but i want all users to be able to access the document library ,, but only specifc user/s to be able to sync.. now if i follow ur appraoch then users wil not be able to access the SP library at all...is this correct?

Comment: If you give other users View or Read permission only, they will be able to access the library but they will not be able to add New Item

Comment: ok thanks for the info .. but this is not related to my question..